# Is it possible to use self-documenting f-strings in python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.7, f-string

As of version 3.8 python offers the possibility of using what is called [self-documenting f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging):

```py
user = 'eric_idle'
member_since = date(1975, 7, 31)
f'{user=} {member_since=}'
"user='eric_idle' member_since=datetime.date(1975, 7, 31)"
```

My question here is simple: is it possible to import this from future and use it in python 3.7?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, a language feature like this is unlikely to be supported in previous versions.

Furthermore, it isn't mentioned on [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html)'s docs.

Comment: Right, thanks, your answer contains the method to answer future questions like this: search in the `__future__` docs if available.